# Country not showing up in country list

Tags: magento-2.1

i want to use "Curaçao" as a country. It is listed in the "vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml" but i do not see it in the country drop down list.

Does anyone know how i can get it to show up in the list? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll also need to add Curaçao to the directory listing in your store. If you have access to the database, you can test using SQL statements, then create a custom module and InstallData script that can be used again in the future.

For more information on the installer script method, you can see how Magento is creating the initial directory items on [Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Directory/Setup/InstallData.php).

**Testing with SQL Queries**

1. Add a record to the `directory_country` table, referencing the territory code from the Zend Locale file.

   ```
   INSERT INTO `directory_country` (`country_id`, `iso2_code`, `iso3_code`) VALUES('CW', 'CW', 'CUW');
   ```
2. Create the default region *(same as the country, in this case)*

   ```
   INSERT INTO `directory_country_region` (`country_id`, `code`, `default_name`)VALUES('CW', 'CUW', 'Curaçao');
   ```
3. Finally, add a region name reference.

   ```
   INSERT INTO `directory_country_region_name` (`locale`, `region_id`, `name`)
   VALUES('en_US', 
       (SELECT `region_id` FROM `directory_country_region` WHERE `country_id` = 'CW'), 'Curaçao');
   ```

Assuming you don't receive any errors, you should be able to clear cache and see Curaçao as an option.
[image: Custom Country in Magento 2 Listing]

Comment: Thank you. I did the above steps but i still can not see it. Am i overlooking something?

Comment: It's more than a year later, but u totally forgot to accept the answer. thx.

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2.3.4 curacauo is already available.

If you are in older versions, you can use @Michael Martin his answer.

In the update to Magento 2.3.4 you will occur no errors, so with future improvements in mind to 2.3.4 this is a fast solution to use for Below Magento 2.3.4

I tested it on magento 2.3.3 then updated to 2.3.4 and no errors.